# Creating links in posts isn't as smooth as it could be

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability

If I take a <strike>URL</strike> website location, e.g. github.com, and highlight it to turn it into a link, even though it's already a valid link, the link-creation tool gives me a blank slate to work with. That is not a smooth process.

So in other words:

- Type out a valid URL like example.com in the body of the post (with the exception of URLs starting with "http://" like "http://example.com").
- Highlight the text.
- Click the link button.
- ***Receive a blank url box and type out that exact URL again.***

Which means that you have to:

- Type out a valid URL like "example.com" in the body of the post (with the exception of URLs starting with "http://" like "http://example.com").
- Highlight the URL.
- Copy the URL.
- Click the link button.
- Receive a blank URL box
- Paste the URL in

It brings a whole other mechanism of copying and pasting into the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put plain link

http://stackoverflow.com

it's transfered to hyperlink automatically.

So you don't have to do these steps if you do not want to [change text to hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yep, which is simple, but generally ugly.

Comment: so you want to keep only example.com instead of that one with http:// ?

Comment: Yeah, generally putting the info into a crafted hyperlink is both more readable, and it's probably more discover-able for new users, who aren't going to be able to guess that adding a http:// before their url will have the correct behavior.  It's great that there is more than one way to create a good link, but the cleaner way isn't as trivially simple as it could be.  (Obviously this is not a huge deal, just a papercut).

Comment: Just putting http:// in is good enough, I guess, I doubt it's an annoyance for too many other people anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario you describe is quite unusual because

- The words you highlight from the post are normally a description of the page the link takes to.
- In the case the user doesn't want to use a description for the link, or that description is already provided in another part of the post, such as right before the link, the user will simply write the link directly in the post.

To notice that example.com is not a URL; it's a domain name. To be a URL it should report the scheme, even though the browser will normally accept a domain name as URL because they will automatically add the scheme, which is "http://" by default.

Comment: I can't comment on unusual or not because I have exactly only a case study to go on, which is simply my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Please prepopulate the url box with a url if the highlighted text is a valid url already.

e.g.  if I highlight example.com and click the link icon, it should prepopulate the box with http://example.com

Comment: just write http:// before it: http://example.com ... BTW: this is not answer!

Comment: Sure it is.  In the context of the meta, using a feature-request tag, it's useful for the question to be the problem, and the answer to be the solution, because then alternative solutions to the problem can be posted.

Comment: alternative/suggestion should be in question I think, and answer should be suggestion from another user/ notification from moderator

Comment: This approach allows people to vote up solutions on their own merit, and problems on their own merit.  If my problem is valid but my solution isn't, they can be weighed separately, and vice versa.

Comment: SOP here is to do as @genesis said, and if someone else has a different proposed solution, it can be posted as a separate feature request.

Comment: I've explained my exact reasons for interpreting the question, in this context, as a stand-in for the problem to solve, and the answers for stand-ins for solutions.  Indeed, in the past I have proposed multiple answers as solutions so that viewers can vote up whichever they find most apt, which isn't especially possible when the solutions are put in the question body itself.  It just makes sense from that aspect. *shrugs*